# Shell/ Bash Nested loop – Automator Folder Action

Tags: shell, svg, npm, converters, automator

How can I automate the process of saving an SVG in multiple resolutions or file formats? Without the need to open any application such as Illustrator? Also how can I generate a retina ready fallback versions of that SVG?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Node.js module **[svgexport (download)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgexport)** and **Automator** on Mac OS!

---

**Installation**

First install svg export globally using terminal (“npm” must be installed):

```
npm install svgexport -g
```

---

**Automator**

1. Create three folders e.g. on your desktop for convenient use: **“convert”, “png”, “svg”** (In this example we only generate pngs from the svg, but jpg, pdf or else work, too)
2. Open Automator & create a new folder action (CMD + N). Open & select the just created folder “convert”.
3. Add a “Shell-Script” action from the library
4. Set Shell to “/bin/bash” and “Pass Input” to “as arguments”.

---

**The Script** —
Now let’s add the code and afterwards save the Automator action.

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin export PATH
for i in "$@"; do

  for size in 100 250 640 1024 1600 2000; do
    o="${i%.svg}_$size.png"
    o2x="${i%.svg}_$size@2x.png"
    svgexport "$i" "$o" png 100% $size:
    svgexport "$i" "$o2x" png 100% "$(($size*2))":
    mv "$o" ~/Desktop/png/
    mv "$o2x" ~/Desktop/png/
  done

mv "$i" ~/Desktop/svg/
done
```

---

**Test:**

Now grab a svg, drop it in the convert folder and see the magic happen.

---

**Explanation:**

We have two *for loops*: The first running for each file added to the svg folder, the second creates two versions for each size as listed. One normal and one retina (@2x). We rename the files and add the size to each filename. Finally we move the generated images to png folder and the source svg to the svg folder.

[Here is a great article](https://mijingo.com/blog/creating-an-os-x-folder-action-to-export-svg) that explains the above code in more detail

Comment: nice bash code! I would have gone for an `imagemagick` solution if there was no npm tag.